# Modularity theorem and some results

Tags: elliptic-curves, modular-forms

Let $C$ be an elliptic curve over rationals. Then we can attach to $C$ an L-series $L(C,s)$. I read about the *Modularity theorem*

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularity_theorem

In the section *Statement* I am not able to understood the paragraph from: The modularity theorem implies a closely related analytic ... **to** this is the Hasse–Weil conjecture, which follows from the modularity theorem. Can anyone explain to me this result by another method?

Comment: There are entire books dedicated to summarizing this connection...

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo: can you an example?

Comment: A google search for "elliptic curves modularity theorem" in books: https://www.google.com/search?q=elliptic+curves+modularity+theorem&rlz=1C1LENP_enUS495US495&aq=f&oq=elliptic+curves+modularity+theorem&aqs=chrome.0.57j60j62l2.5951j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=elliptic+curves+modularity+theorem+books&rlz=1C1LENP_enUS495US495&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=jiimUaSBNNHi4AOnqYGIBQ&ved=0CAwQ_AUoAg&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47008514,d.dmg&fp=21273d8bce784d89&biw=1366&bih=681

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, this question is just too broad to make it justice with a short answer. There are entire books dedicated to present even a summary of the connection... For instance, you can read [Milne's book on "Elliptic Curves"](http://www.jmilne.org/math/Books/ectext5.pdf). The modularity theorem is the main subject of chapter V. In particular, see section 5 (numbered page 208) and Conjecture 5.1.